# Kantorovich duality with pseudometric

Tags: real-analysis, probability, optimal-transport

The usual framework for the Kantorovich duality in optimal transport theory uses Polish spaces as ground spaces for the distributions that should be transported. Are there results available that generalize the setting to pseudometric spaces? Or is this impossible?